# How do I use MySQL Views with Ms Access 2007 without getting junk for string columns?

Tags: mysql, ms-access

## Overview of problem:

I have a Ms Access 2007 front end connected to a MySQL database. I created a view in MySQL as I couldn't generate the same view in Access it's self and that works fine from MySQL's Workbench software but if I use a "Select * from myView" in a MS Access 2007 db I get everything from random Chinese character to "Long Binary Data" for what should be strings.

## How to replicate:

To help you understand my problem and hopefully replicate it I wrote the following explanation:

First create a table and populate it in MySQL using the following code:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `aTestTbl`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `aTestTbl`;
CREATE TABLE `aTestTbl` (
  `ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ExternalID` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `SomeValue` varchar(25) NOT NULL
);

--
-- Dumping data for table `aTestTbl`
--

LOCK TABLES `aTestTbl` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `aTestTbl` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `aTestTbl` VALUES (1,1,'Value1');
INSERT INTO `aTestTbl` VALUES (2,1,'Value2');
INSERT INTO `aTestTbl` VALUES (3,2,'Value3');
INSERT INTO `aTestTbl` VALUES (4,2,'Value4');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `aTestTbl` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Now create a MySQL View FROM the following SQL:

```
SELECT ExternalID,
    group_concat(distinct SomeValue order by SomeValue ASC separator ', ') AS `ExtVal`
FROM aTestTbl
GROUP BY ExternalID;
```

Then run the following SQL to ensure it all worked:

```
SELECT *
FROM new_view;
```

It should produce something like:

```
|ExternalID  | SomeValue      |
|1           | Value1, Value2 |
|2           | Value3, Value4 |
```

If you then connect that table into an MS Access 2007 DB and put the same SQL

```
SELECT *
FROM new_view;
```

into a new query I hope (as I do) you get something like:

```
|ExternalID  | SomeValue        |
|1           | Long Binary Data |
|2           | Long Binary Data |
```

I have tried to use a CAST(*val* AS CHAR) around the value but that didn't help

## Question(s):

1. Why is this?
2. How can I get Access to show the correct string?

Comment: I have managed to solve the problem using a Pass-Though query in MS Access but would still like to leave this question up to see if anyone knows why I can't use MySQL views in MS Access 2007.

Comment: I have also discovered that just a view of a table (with string columns) produces the same "Long Binary Data" for every string column!

Comment: Have you tried deleting and recreating your linked tables? Perhaps some out-of-date metadata from a previous version of your MySQL tables is causing this problem. Just refreshing the links doesn't clean out all the metadata, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks David but it's not that. My db deletes and reconnects all tables etc on login and that example is for a brand spanking new db made just for this question. :)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this is no longer an issue. I just tested this with...

- Access_2010 using a "linked table" to the MySQL view `new_view`
- via the MySQL ODBC 5.2w Driver
- against MySQL 5.5.29-0ubuntu0.12.04.2

...and the view displays properly in Access:

[image: MySQL_view]

Comment: hehe you going for the http://stackoverflow.com/badges/17/necromancer badge with this one? ;) Haven't used Access for like a year+ so can't test it. If you get your 5 upvotes (and d badge) I will assume it is correct and mark it as such. :)

Comment: @GazB I had all the bits and pieces already in place so I figured "Why not?" :) I also had some frustrating experiences with older versions of MySQL ODBC so I thought I'd see if things had improved.